# Java CASE why do i get a complete differet int back with and without using ' '

Tags: java, case

As a Java beginner I'm playing around with a case statement at this point.

I have set: `int d = '1';` And with: `System.out.println("number is: " + d);`, this returns 51.

Now I found out that if I set it as: `int d = 1;`, it does return 1.

Now my question is why does it return 49 when I set it as '3'? What difference do the ' ' make?

My code that returns 49:

```
int a = '1';

    switch(a)
    {
        case '1' :
        System.out.println("Good");
        break;
        case '2' :
        case '3' :
        System.out.println("great");
        break;
        default :
        System.out.println("invalid");
    }
    System.out.println("value: " + a);
```

Comment: `'1'` is a character, not a number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With ' (single quotes) around a character you tell the compiler that the value in between is a character (variable type char in Java). Generally, computers only understand numbers so characters get represented as numbers in memory as well. The value of the character '1' is 49. You want to actually save the value 1 in memory and use that to calculate things. So, you have to tell the compiler that you want this to be interpreted as an actual number and not as a character.

To summarize:

- '1' is the character that prints the number 1
- 1 is the actual number 1

This means 1 and '1' have different integer values.

You can look at the integer value of the most commonly used characters in coding here: [ASCII Table](http://www.asciitable.com/)

Comment: that makes sense, intresting.
Will play around a bit more with this.
Thank you very much

Comment: It's not really accurate to say that ASCII represents most characters.  It's not even 1% of all characters.  It would be more accurate to say that ASCII represents the most commonly used characters (in code).

Comment: @VGR That is true and closer to what I meant in the first place.

Answer (score 7):

`'1'` is the character '1', whose integer value is 49. Each character has a numeric value in the range from 0 to 2^16-1. Therefore 1 and '1' are different integer values.

Comment: ah i see, this makes more sense.
Will dig up some more information about this, didn't really heard anything about this before.
Thank you very much

Comment: @Char Ironically, your name is `Char`. :)

Answer (score 1):

In Java the character values are stored as int internally. That means when you assign a char value using 'A' to an int type, the compiler casts the char value into int and thus the UTF-16 Code unit value is stored into the int variable.

Try this one as well:

```
 int yourInt = 33;
 char ch = (char) yourInt;
 System.out.println(yourInt);
 System.out.println(ch);
```

Comment: Not ASCII; UTF-16 code unit, one or two of which encode a Unicode codepoint.

Answer (score 0):

1 is interpreted as a character whose value is 49.

Do:

```
int a = 1;

switch(a) {
    case 1:
    ...
```

Or, if you go with your current code:

```
System.out.println("value: " + Integer.parseInt((char)a+'');
```

Answer (score 0):

It is happens because for some weird reason java treat char type as short.
Your '1' expression is constant expression of type char. It is stored internally as some numeric value. Usually all goes fine with this approach for example `System.out.println('1')` will print exactly what you expect.

But when you write `int a = '1';` you char value is converted to int value because char behave like short int there.

PS: if there was no implicit conversion between char and int (which anyway have no sense) you just got compilation error.

Comment: Java has [shorts](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) and why wouldn't you want a data type for chars? They are different and serve different purposes.

Comment: Yes. My mistake long time since I saw it last time :) Will fix my answer.

Answer (score 0):

When you declare int d='1'; then 1 is not treated as  integer it is a character. It is converted to 49 according its unicode value. similarly character '3' will coverted to 51. Jvm do implicit type casting from character to integer.
you should try this code

```
char c = '3';
    int a ='1';
    System.out.println(c);
    System.out.println((int)c);
```

You will get output as

3

51

49